# Объединить строки python

Tags: python

Есть 3 строки в списке:

```
lst = ["текст_1", "текст_2", "текст_3"]
```

Нужно объединить в одну строку, чтобы получилось так:

```
"текст_1, текст_2, текст_3"
```

Comment: всего лишь ', '.join(lst)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = ["текст_1", "текст_2", "текст_3"]

print(', '.join(lst))
```

Comment: *Есть 3 строки в списке:* - вы их еще строчнее  :) хотите сделать? :)